# How to edit this function so that the number of iterations doesn't need to be specified?

Tags: r, function

Suppose we have the following functions: `euclid` calculates the Euclidean distance and `k_means` implements the k-means algorithm.

```
euclid <- function(points1, points2) {
  distanceMatrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(points1)[1], ncol=dim(points2)[1])
  for(i in 1:nrow(points2)) {
    distanceMatrix[,i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(points1)-points2[i,])^2))
  }
  distanceMatrix
}

k_means <- function(x, centers, distFun, nItter) {
  clusterHistory <- vector(nItter, mode="list")
  centerHistory <- vector(nItter, mode="list")
  
  for(i in 1:nItter) {
    distsToCenters <- distFun(x, centers)
    clusters <- apply(distsToCenters, 1, which.min)
    centers <- apply(x, 2, tapply, clusters, mean)
    # Saving history
    clusterHistory[[i]] <- clusters
    centerHistory[[i]] <- centers
    if(i >1){
      if(identical(clusterHistory[[i]], clusterHistory[[i-1]])){break} #Stop if duplicated result
  }}
  
  list(clusters=clusterHistory, centers=centerHistory)
}

test=data # A data.frame
ktest=as.matrix(test) # Turn into a matrix
centers <- ktest[sample(nrow(ktest), 4),] # Sample some centers, 4 for example

result <- k_means(ktest, centers, euclid, 4) # 4 iterations
print(result)
```

Currently, `k_means` has an option to include number of iterations (4 here). It breaks when the next iteration matches the previous one as the function has converged.

However, how could I edit this function slightly so that I don't have to specify the number of iterations  (`nItter`) and instead just have the function run until it converges and breaks automatically?

Comment: Incidentally, the `sqrt` call is unnecessary: you can use a `euclidSquared` distance function (i.e. the same as now, just leaving off the `sqrt`). For the purpose of clustering by distance this is the same, since the square root is a continuous, monotonously increasing function on the domain in question. The only difference is therefore that your code will run slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`while`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Control.html) or `repeat` instead of `for`.

Since you no longer have a number of iterations, you probably wouldn’t preallocate the result lists, and use `c` to append a new element, rather than accessing the `i`-th index.

The resulting code is admittedly quite atypical R code: unless you have a specific use for the history of the algorithm, I recommend not allocating lists, and rather only retaining the last two elements of the history.

```
k_means = function(x, centers, distFun) {
  prevClusters = NULL
  prevCenters = NULL
  
  repeat {
    distsToCenters = distFun(x, centers)
    clusters = apply(distsToCenters, 1L, which.min)
    centers = apply(x, 2L, tapply, clusters, mean)
    if (identical(prevClusters, clusters)) break
    
    prevClusters = clusters
    prevCenters = centers
  }
  
  list(clusters = clusters, centers = centers)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to show how many times the code repeated so that we can tell how many iterations were necessary for the convergence now that it isn't specified anymore?